# Loop computation - Sum of integers that are devidable

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, sum, integer

I am looking for a way to compute the sum of integers between 1 and 20 that can be divided by 2, 3 or 5.

I created an array with the integers from 1 to 20.
`Y= np.arange(1, 21, 1)`

I know the computation and checking should be done in loop, potentially if loop that checks if Y can be divided by 2, 3 or 5 and then if the statement is true make the true statements add up. How can I do that?

I tried it the following way but there is an error

```
for i in np.arange(1, 21, 1):
    if i%2 ==0:
    print(x=0)
    else 
    print(x=i)
```

I thought the code above would give me an vector x where the I from the range is 0 if it cannot be divided by to and the value of the integer i if it can be divided by 2.
how can I fix the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking advantage of you're already using numpy you can do the following:

```
def get_divisible_by_n(arr, n):
    return arr[arr%n == 0]

x = np.arange(1,21)

get_divisible_by_n(x, 2)
#array([ 2,  4,  6,  8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20])

get_divisible_by_n(x, 5)
#array([ 5, 10, 15, 20])
```

the condition for a number to be divided by n is `number%n == 0`. When you do `arr[arr%n == 0]` you're applying the condition to every position of the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the modulo operator:

```
5%5 = 0
5%3=2
4%2 = 0
```

so as long as x % n  is unequal to 0 it is not divisible

Answer (score 0):

How to check if a number is dividable by another? Easy, just check if the remainder of dividing a by b is zero with `%` operator, check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator).

Example:

```
def is_dividable_by_2(n):
    return bool(n % 2 == 0)


num = 5

if is_dividable_by_2(num):
    print('%s is dividable by two' % num)
else:
    print('%s is not dividable by two' % num)

num = 4
if is_dividable_by_2(num):
    print('%s is dividable by two' % num)
else:
    print('%s is not dividable by two' % num)
```

Output:

```
$ python dividable.py 
5 is not dividable by two
4 is dividable by two
```